# R time series multiple lines plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I have a very big dataset that I'd like to illustrate using plotly in R.
A sample of my dataset is shown below:

```
    > new_data_2
# Groups:   newdatum [8]
  date       activity       totaal
  <date>     <fct>          <int>
1 2019-11-21 N11            144
2 2019-09-22 N11            129
3 2019-05-15 N22            117
4 2019-01-23 N22            12
5 2019-07-04 N22            12
6 2019-07-18 N22            12
...
```

For every activity I want to display the amount (totaal) per date (date) in a time series plot.
Somehow I don't get it right in R. Somehow I need to group my activity to display, but I can't figure it out.

```
new_data_2 %>% 
group_by(activity) %>% 
plot_ly(x=new_data_2$newdatum) %>% 
add_lines(y=~new_data_2$totaal, color = ~factor(newdatum))
```

It does display an empty plot and not with the 'activity' on the left side.

What i want to achieve is:

[image: this image]

Comment: Please provide a reprex your data can't be easily used in r, try to use dput

Comment: @Dave - Did you have any luck with any of the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but after the `group_by()` you need to tell R to do something to the groups.

```
new_data_2 %>%
  group_by(activity, date) %>%  # use two groupings since you want by activity & date 
  summarise(totaal_2 = sum(totaal))
```

That should get to the dataframe you're looking for.  You can use ggplot & plotly on it from there.

I would recommend reshaping the data first (as above), saving it as a new object, and then graphing it.  Doing it this way helps you see each step along the way.  Pipes `%>%` are great, but can make each step difficult to see.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be very obvious at first, but the structure of your data is ideal for plot with multiple time series. You don't even need to worry with the `group_by` function. Your dataset seems to hava a [long format](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/wide-and-long-data/) where the dates in the `date column` and the names in `activity column` are not unique. But you will have only *one* variable per activity and date.

Given the correct specifications, `plot_ly()` will group your data using `color=~activity` like this: `p <- plot_ly(new_data2, x = ~date, y = ~totall, color = ~activity) %>% add_lines()`. Since you haven't provided a data sample that is large enough, I'll use the built-in dataset `economics_long` to show you how you can do this. First of all, notice how the structure of my sampled dataset matches yours:

```
           date variable value
1    1967-07-01  psavert  12.5
2    1967-08-01  psavert  12.5
3    1967-09-01  psavert  11.7
4    1967-10-01  psavert  12.5
5    1967-11-01  psavert  12.5
6    1967-12-01  psavert  12.1
...
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

# data
data("economics_long")
df <- data.frame(economics_long)

# keep only some variables that have values on a comparable level
df <- df %>% filter(!(variable %in% c('pop', 'pce', 'unemploy')))

# plotly time series
p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y = ~value, color = ~variable) %>%
  add_lines()

# show plot
p
```